# Investigate convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

Investigate convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$

I applied nth term test and was inconclusive.

I tried ratio test but I don't know how to evaluate the limit. I think it is 1 therefore also inconclusive.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I was thinking by saying this series is greater than the harmonic series but this is untrue for smaller values of n.

Comment: It does not matter that this is untrue for small values of n. What matters is that $\ln(n) > 1$ for sufficiently large $n$. (in this case for $n>1$)

Comment: For convergence/divergence, the first $2$ terms, or the first $20000$, do not matter.

Comment: Ok so I could compare it to the harmonic series then?

Comment: @Dark $n>2$, actually.

Comment: @Did indeed, thanks.

Comment: Compare it to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Ok great thanks!

Comment: $\ln(n)/n\neq \ln(n/e^n)$. You are misremembering the logarithm rule: we have $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(a/b)$, not $\ln(a)/\ln(b)=\ln(a/b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**: $(n > e)  \Rightarrow \ln n > 1$

**Hint 2**: Neglecting finite number of elements from a series doesn't change it's convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Because the sequence defining this series is eventually monotonically decreasing (that is, there exists a point after which the sequence is monotonically decreasing), we can apply the Cauchy condensation test:
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty 2^n \frac{\ln(2^n)}{2^n}=\ln(2)\sum_{n=3}^\infty n= \infty$$

Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}=\infty$.