# Find the domain of $x$ for the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**Question:** Find the domain of $x$ for the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)^{x}.$$

**My Approach:** The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)^{x}$
diverges for $x\leq0$ by $n$th term divergence test.

The series diverges for $x=1$ by [Investigate convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763041/investigate-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-lnnn). I can not prove that series diverges for 0 $< x < 1$.

**The Book mentions the answer** $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $0< x\leq 1$, and $n\geq 3$,
$$\frac{1}{n^x}\leq \left(\dfrac{\log n}{n}\right)^{x}.$$
Moreover, for $x> 1$,
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{\left(\dfrac{\log n}{n}\right)^{x}}{\dfrac{1}{n^{(x+1)/2}}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{(\log n)^{x}}{n^{(x-1)/2}}=0$$
implies that for $n$ sufficiently large,
$$\left(\dfrac{\log n}{n}\right)^{x}\leq \frac{1}{n^{(x+1)/2}}.$$

Answer (score 5):

For large $n$, $0<\dfrac{\log n}{n}<1$, so $\dfrac{\log n}{n}\leq\left(\dfrac{\log n}{n}\right)^{x}$ for $0<x<1$.